# Can there be true but unprovable statements about object other than numbers?

Tags: incompleteness, formal-systems, provability

In ZFC, everything is a pure set, and because the necessary amount of arithmetic for the Gödel's incompleteness theorems to go through is interpretable within ZFC, there are undecidable statements about sets as well.

This really blows my mind, because there are not only number-theoretic facts beyond our reach, but also relations between sets that are true but unprovable.

These may not be interesting questions about sets, but still.

My question: **are there interesting relations between mathematical objects other than sets that are true but unprovable because of Gödel's incompleteness theorems?**

Comment: In Graph Theory, you have Kruskal's Tree Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_tree_theorem (where "unprovable" is taken to mean "unprovable in Peano Arithmetic").

Comment: This is a very difficult question to formulate, in large part because you depend on having entities in maths which cannot be represented in sets, which leaves you with some rather untame subjects.

Comment: The title says "numbers", the body says "sets". Perhaps you're so strongly committed to numbers being sets that it doesn't make a difference for you; still it would be good to make the formulations consistent.